# How to get that terminal button on right click?

Tags: terminal, windows-terminal

How to get the terminal button on right click on widows?
The btn looks like this
[Terminal Btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M09wb.png)

On click of that btn, it opens the terminal.
[Termianl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb8hn.png)

Comment: Hold shift while right-clicking... Is that what you need? As long as you installed the terminals, it should appear

Comment: This is not shift + rightclick. This terminal btn appears on single right click.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Terminal Preview v1.1.1671.0 and later installers put the Windows Terminal in the context menu.
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.1.1671.0

But if you have an older version, you need to update the Windows Registry.
Create a `wterminal.reg` text file and put the following code in it and then run it. Also, make sure paths to `wt.exe` and `wt_32.ico` files are correct on your system. You can change those paths according to your system.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\wt]
@="Windows terminal here"
"Icon"="%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\terminal\\wt_32.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\wt\command]
@="%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe"
```

***Warning: Be careful and make sure you have a backup of the Windows Registry before applying any changes.***

Here you can find more information about it: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1060#issuecomment-497539461

Comment: This adds the terminal option to the right-click in directory, but not when you right-click specific program.